# Where does this line of code return to?

Tags: swift

In the code below, I'm confused as to where the `return` statement in the code returns to? When executed, it works as expected, but does it return to:

```
if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping == true
```

or does it return to:

```
if let digit = sender.currentTitle
```

Below is the full chunk of code where this applies.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
private var decimalUsed = false

@IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: UIButton)
{
    if let digit = sender.currentTitle {

        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping == true {

            if digit == "." && decimalUsed == true {
                return   //where does this return to?
            } else if digit == "." && decimalUsed == false {
                decimalUsed = true
            }


            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit

        } else {
            display.text = digit
        }

        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true

    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, that code is not an example of good code. It's rather terrible. Never compare with booleans explicitly. Also, there is no need for `decimalUsed` variable. You can check that dynamically by checking the current text. The code could be also simplified using `guard` clauses.

Comment: Srsly, how can you *not* know where it returns to? If there were closure involved or anything I would understand a little uncertainty - but this is a plain old function with a plain old `return`. Please read your tutorial(s) again on what `return` means.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan! I'll definitely take your comments into consideration. I'm still learning the ropes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `return` always returns out of the function, so in this case it returns to the line of code that calls `touchDigit(...)`

Basically here, the `return` just stops the execution of the `touchDigit` function.

(*Which means that none of the code following the `return` will be run*)

Comment: You may want to elaborate that it stops the execution of the `touchDigit` function and that everything after that return will not be run.

Comment: @Ike10 In my opinion "stopping the execution" already implies that nothing after that will be run, but I added it anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` simply stops the code. You can put it in functions if you would like. For example:

If I want to continue running some code only if a certain statement is true, then you can `return` the function to stop it if it is false.

```
func something(a: Int, b: Int) {
    if a != b {
        return//Stops the code
    }
    //Some more code -- if a is not equal to b, this will not be called
}
```

Remember, this only works with `void` functions. It can work with others as well, but that is slightly different. You must return something along with it. Another example:

```
func somethingElse(a: Int, b: Int) -> Bool{
    if a != b {
        return false //stops the code, but also returns a value
    }
    return true //Will only get called if a == b
}
```

In this function, it is return a `Boolean`. If a != b, then `return false` is written because that returns false while also stoping the code.

For more on returns, you can visit [Apple's documentation on functions.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)