# Register user to firebase and sign in if already registered

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code to register a user to firebase...

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!) {(user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                if error.localizedDescription == "FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse"
                {
                   //sign in here?
                }

            }
            else {
                print("User signed in!")
            }
        } }
    else{
        print("You left email/password empty")
    }
```

What would I add to this so it automatically signs in if the user was already created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the authentication methods Firebase provides. E.g. in your case, this one would be most suitable:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

**EDIT**

The error response from the registration method you posted will tell you if the given user already exist. In which case, you can just make a call to the signIn method automatically from within the callback.

Looking at the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-createuserwithemailpasswordcompletion), I see the error code you should look for is FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse.

Comment: Knowing the error code, how do I check for that specific error code and react to it?

Comment: @Goomba I'm talking about the callback from the registration method you posted. The error object is accessible to you whenever a response from the backend hits your code. This is when you'll check if the error variable contains anything interesting.

Comment: Ok but how would I check for the error, is it a string? Like do I check for "FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse"? And I assume it would go in the first if statement where the error is printed to check there...

Comment: If you read the docs I linked to, it's all specified there. That said, I agree with  Muhammad that your approach probably isn't the best in this case. If a given user tries to register, but the email already exist, just notify the user about this (and provide a means of navigating to the login screen).

Comment: Well I am auto registering the user by iphone UDID and auto logging in by UDID so the user shouldn't know about this as its automated.

Comment: Can you please re check my code and is it something like that what I would do?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054162/handling-errors-in-new-firebase-and-swift

Btw, this is unrelated but, I'm pretty sure UDIDs are not publicly accesible to Apple devs (anymore) due to security concerns. How does your implementation for fetching UDIDs look like?

Comment: I was going to get udid's by: UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString Also thank you for the link, if i could I would mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `currentUser` is not `nil` beforehand:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    // User is signed in.
    // ...
} else {
    // No user is signed in.
    // ...
}
```

From Firebase docs:

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is nil:

Comment: The more correct answer it seems to be from Øyvind Hauge but I don't know how to check for the error code he has pointed out. Thank you though!

Comment: This won't work if the user at some point, for some reason has been logged out (currentUser will be nil in this case)

Comment: Hence, show the login screen. I'm not compelled to make a network call just to check if user is logged in. Official docs use the same check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to use fetchProvidersForEmail:completion: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-fetchprovidersforemailcompletion to check if the email exists first.

This will return the list of provider IDs associated with that email. If you get 'password' in the list then an email/password account already exists for that email, you can call `signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)`. Otherwise, you call `createUserWithEmail(email, password: password)`