# How to parse iOS Firebase Storage error code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I parse the following Firebase Storage error in Swift?

```
storageRef.delete { (error) in   
    if let error = error {    
        print(error)       
    }            
}
```

Print console:

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object images/users/UBTXiedh11fT0s0BydkMuXk2k622/xyz.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={object=images/users/UBTXiedh11fT0s0BydkMuXk2k622/xyz.jpg, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",
    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"
  }
}, bucket=someApp-10010010.appspot.com, data={length = 121, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 54220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object images/users/UBTXiedh11fT0s0BydkMuXk2k622/xyz.jpg does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}
```

I know there is `StorageErrorCode` but I do not know how to get the raw value into it.

```
if let errorCode = StorageErrorCode(rawValue: Int) {
    ...
}
```

The goal is to be able to switch on the error code itself (i.e. 404).

Comment: does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054162/handling-errors-in-new-firebase-and-swift

Comment: `StorageErrorCode` is an `enum`, so you could just switch over `errorCode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must cast your error as `NSError` to get from it the code value (`Int`).  Then you can switch on the `StorageErrorCode` object (`enum`) using the error code as the raw value.

```
storageRef.delete { (error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        let code = StorageErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)

        switch code {
        case .objectNotFound:
            print("object not found") // this is your 404
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation on this is very thin.